# ¿Como puedo ver cuántos objetos tiene un esquema en PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, plsql

Necesito saber cuántos objetos tiene un esquema. Yo tengo puesto la siguiente columna:

```
Select count(*)
from DBA
where DBA.schemas = 'IMPORTACIONES' owner DBA
and schemas rows < 100;
```

Pero no funciona. ¿Alguien sabe cómo solucionarlo?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Que significa que no funciona? ¿te da un error?¿Te retorna un resultado que no estás esperando?

Answer (score 0):

¿Esto te da error?

```js
SELECT count(*) 
FROM DBA 
WHERE schemas = 'IMPORTACIONES' 
AND schemas ROWS < 100;
```

Y si lo quieres con Alias, puedes hacerlo así:

```js
SELECT count(*) AS Cuenta 
FROM DBA d 
WHERE d.schemas = 'IMPORTACIONES' 
AND d.schemas ROWS < 100;
```